# How to implement facebook oEmbed API - Not able to generate App Review

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api, oembed

we're customising a white-label CMS solution for a customer and want to allow for facebook/insta embeds. We would like to implement this feature using facebook's and instagram's [oEmbed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed/#getting-embed-html). However, I am stuck at the point where facebook needs to grant access to that API.

What I've done so far:

- Create a fb dev account
- Create an App
- Go to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and make test calls --> calling the oEmbed-API, referring to posts from `facebook.com/facebook/<somePost>` and `facebook.com/instagram/<somePost>`. I always receive the answer: `(#10) To use 'Oembed Read', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Oembed Read' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.`

According to fb, "Request advanced access" should be enabled 24h after making a Test API call. Therefore I was hoping that this would allow me to request advanced access for the oEmbed-API (not talking about *using* the API yet, but just *requesting* access).

However I am still stuck at that point and cannot request advanced access for any feature. I went through the [getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/get-started/) a dozen times and I am stuck with this ticket for ten days now.

**Has anybody recently made good experiences with creating a new App and asking for oEmbed-API access? Which steps did you take?**